# R: function By - treat one-row and multiple-row subset the same

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I'm trying to achieve a very simple function: count the number of rows per subset of a matrix selected using "by" (m1 is a 4 column matrix):

```
by(m1, m1[,2:4], nrow)
```

But I get error "arguments must have same length". From what I understand, the selected subset is a vector rather than a matrix, when it has only one row. Therefore, "nrow" becomes invalid. How can I handle this?

Comment: You could add `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` and you won't get subsets of vectors but matrices/data.frames of nrow = 1.

Answer (score 3):

The NROW function works on matrices, dataframes and vectors.

```
> NROW(1:3)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that `nrow` is only valid for matrix arguments, so why not pass in a matrix?

```
> nrow(1:3)
NULL
> nrow(matrix(1:3,ncol=3))
[1] 1
```

You can just replace your call to `nrow` with `function(x) nrow(matrix(x,ncol=3))`. The full expression would be

```
by(m1, m1[,2:4], function(x) nrow(matrix(x,ncol=3)))
```